# what's the meaning when GNU C lib hsearch_r return negative int?

Tags: c, gnu

```
int status;
status=hsearch_r(wishFind,FIND,&(h->retElem),(h->htab));
print("Debug: status is %d\n",status);
```

the result show status is -8400
    but the wishFind is not in h->htab.

```
I think status need to be 0.
it's confused me that status is -8400.
Thanks!
```

Comment: Is that the actual code ? There's no such C function called print , the current glibc hsearch_r function only returns 0 or 1, so something else is going on (e.g. you're invoking undefined behavior somewhere in the code, possibly corrupting memory . or there's an error in your debugging)

Comment: thanks, not real code ,and I miss "f". I will debug about memory.

Comment: hi all, the problem is on memory which in other section of code

Answer (score 1):

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch):

> hsearch_r() returns nonzero on success, and 0 on error.

That means it's allowed to return *any* non-zero value on success so you need to cater for that:

```
if (status == 0) {
    // failure
} else {
    // success
}
```

If what you're looking for really *isn't* in the hash table, you have a problem quite separate from the code you've shown us.